# Listen page content updated

Tags: javascript, html, asynchronous, google-chrome-extension, dom-events

Since ajax is used widely today, many page contents are loaded asynchronously. Is there any way to know something is loaded after all DOMs are loaded? For example, whole page is loaded, but some images are created/loaded by `new image()`, how can I know these kinds of change happened in the web page by Javascript? Any event could be useful?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The mutation events as already mentioned should do the trick. If using jQuery, you can do something like this with the 'DOMSubtreeModified' mutation event:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('body').bind('DOMSubtreeModified', 'test', function () {
        alert('something changed');
    });

    $('#some-button').click(function () {
        $('body').append('<h4>added content</h4>');
    });
});
```

Any content changes will display the alert box. In that example, when a button with id "some-button" is clicked, content is added to the body and the alert is shown. The mutation events offer some more specific type of events, the one I have shown is probably the most general.

Comment: Those events have been deprecated, Use the following instead: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

Answer (score 1):

There are some mutation events: http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-DOM-Level-2-Events-20001113/events.html#Events-MutationEvent

`onsubtreemodified`
`onnodeinserted`
`onnoderemoved`
etc.
Look at here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM_Events

Answer (score 1):

Following is a code piece which may help:-

```
<script>
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = "http://static.yourwebsite.com/filename.ext";
    img.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if((img.readyState == "complete") || (img.readyState == 4)) {
            alert("Image loaded dynamically!");
        }
    };
</script>
```

You must change the image source. The event `onreadystatechange` will help you to find out if the image has been loaded or not. `readyState` must be `complete` or `4` as sent by AJAX if I'm not mistaken when the page is fetched.

OR YOU MAY GO WITH

```
<script>
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = "http://static.yourwebsite.com/filename.ext";
    img.onload = function(){
        alert("Image loaded dynamically!");
    };
</script>
```

CREDIT FOR THE ABOVE CODE: http://www.techrepublic.com/article/preloading-and-the-javascript-image-object/5214317

In this code piece, we use `onload` event to trigger the image load

Hope this helps. Mark this as the answer if this helps! :D

Cheers

Comment: Bad for me is, I do not know there is or not such things will be added into the webpage :( But it is still good to know. Thank you very much!

Comment: Mention not, glad helping you